# error in if ((mmMatrix[mmMatrix[, "construct"] == construct, "type"][1] == : missing value, where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, na

I am using SEMinR package to run Structural Equation Models, no missing values in my dataset. I specified the model and once I try to fit data, the error occurs:

**This is my model:**

```
national_mm= constructs(
  composite('NatCont', multi_items('nat_',1:4)))

model_nat_sm=relationships(
  paths(from='NatCont',to=c('coauthor','imfjourn')))

modelnational=estimate_pls(data=dataNational, measurement_model = national_mm, structural_model = model_nat_sm)
```

**This is an error that occurs:**

> error in if ((mmMatrix[mmMatrix[, "construct"] == construct,
> "type"][1] ==  :   missing value, where TRUE/FALSE  needed